# what is SQL Server 2012 required memory for bigger databases

Tags: sql-server, configuration, system-requirements

I was reading  through [this MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.110).aspx) document to check whether my servers resources is enough or not. i found an interesting requirements which does not have a further clarification online,

> Recommended: At least 4 GB and should be increased as database size
>   increases to ensure optimal performance.

can any body give more information on how much memory should increase when the data increase? (ex: for each extra 10gb  we'll need an extra 1gb of memory  or for each 100 table/SP we'll need an additional gb)

Comment: RAM is cheap compared to SQL Server licenses, so just buy a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

There is not a good answer for your question. The required memory depends on many factors and one of them is database size.

Number of users, volume of server request, concurrency, your codes (like ETL and procedures) and many more factors are involved.

The right way to find out how much memory your need, is monitoring the server using tools and also performance monitor on Windows.

You need to see if Memory is your bottleneck or not. If your bottleneck is DISK , CPU or Network bandwidth, adding more memory won't help and is not required.

**Edit:**

Data size alone doesn't mean anything. You may have terabyte database but your reports and applications work on small chunks of data at the same time. Note that having more ram, helps SQL Server for data caching, sorting and other internal data processing. If your report read only 100K records, you don't need large amount of RAM. If your report processes large volume of data with (aggregation, sorting, grouping), having more RAM improves performance.

If you are looking for a formula to determine required RAM per each GB data, I don't know that formula. You may ask DBA site or do more research.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: what if data increased dramatically in production or connections multiplied * 100 due to last date of submission for example. I'm looking for a way to determine what's needed in advance  (other than load testing) specially i know I have flaw in design where the reporting and sql server are on the same machine.